# Formatting a php created CSV file (headings on top row, data on second row)

Tags: php, sql, csv, formatting, export

`header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"yourfile.csv\"");`

i am using this to produce a CSV file;

Currently it is displaying the data as;

Heading, Data, Heading 2, Data 2, Heading 3, Data 3...

i want to display the data as;

**heading, heading 2, heading 3
data 1,  data 2,    data 3**

How would this be done ?

```
    <?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM survey
        WHERE id = '".sql_escape($s)."'";
$row = fetch0ne($sql);

if(!empty($row)) {

    $int = array();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM survey_interests
            WHERE survey = '".sql_escape($s)."'";
    $interests = fetchAll($sql);

    if(!empty($interests)) {
        foreach($interests as $item) {
            $int[] = getInterest($item['interest']);
        }
    }


header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"yourfile.csv\"");   
?>
Full Name, <?php echo $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']; ?>, Age, <?php echo $row['age']; ?>, Gender, <?php echo $row['gender'] == 'm' ? 'Male' : 'Female'; ?>, Country, <?php echo getCountry($row['country']); ?>, <?php if(!empty($int)) { ?><?php echo implode(", ",$int); ?><?php } ?>, Favorite colour, <?php echo getColour($row['colour']); ?>, Favorite search engine, <?php echo getSearchEngines($row['search_engine']); ?>

<?php

}
?>
```

Comment: You've shown us your headers, but haven't shown us the actual code that is producing the data, which is where your error is.  Can you update your question with the relevant code?

Comment: We would probably need to see how you're creating the CSV file as well. Where is the data coming from, what are you doing to it, that kind of thing.

Comment: the data is coming from the database after a session has been stored let me post you the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change you code up:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM survey
        WHERE id = '".sql_escape($s)."'";
$row = fetch0ne($sql);

if(!empty($row)) {

    $int = array();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM survey_interests
            WHERE survey = '".sql_escape($s)."'";
    $interests = fetchAll($sql);

    if(!empty($interests)) {
        foreach($interests as $item) {
            $int[] = getInterest($item['interest']);
        }
    }


header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"yourfile.csv\"");   
?>
Full Name, Age, Gender, Country, Favorite colour, Favorite search engine
<?php echo $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']; ?>, <?php echo $row['age']; ?>, <?php echo $row['gender'] == 'm' ? 'Male' : 'Female'; ?>, <?php echo getCountry($row['country']); ?>, <?php echo getColour($row['colour']); ?>, <?php echo getSearchEngines($row['search_engine']); ?>

<?php

}
?>
```

Comment: all that was required was to put the headings and the code on separate lines, man you rock Neal !

Answer (score 0):

I think your data are like bellow -

```
$records = array(
               [0] = array(heading=>data 1, heading 2=>data 2, heading 3=>data 3),
               [1] = array(heading=>data 1, heading 2=>data 2, heading 3=>data 3),
               [2] = array(heading=>data 1, heading 2=>data 2, heading 3=>data 3),
               [3] = array(heading=>data 1, heading 2=>data 2, heading 3=>data 3)
           );
```

You can follow the following concepts -

```
$heading = implode(',', array_keys( array_pop($records) ) );

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"yourfile.csv\"");

echo $heading."\n\r"; // HEADER IS BEING PLACED HERE

foreach($records as $row){ // CONTENTS IS BEING PLACED HERE
    echo implode(',', $row)."\n\r";
}
exit;
```